# IE11: select element freezes on changing option.text

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am using plain javascript for changing option's text to something else on some event. After that Select(multiselect) element freezes.If I comment line 2 below,then Select element will not freeze.Any suggestions? I want to use javascript only.

```
function updateSelect(select)
{
 var opt = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
opt.text =  "-";//--2
..
..
}
```

Comment: did you get any error in your console?

Comment: I didn't get any error in the console it was just freezing.Anyway I am able to do it with jquery. 

$("#"+opt.id).text("-" );

Comment: you can try this one without using jquery, `document.getElementById(opt.id).innerText = '-';` not sure if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it with Jquery with `.text()` function.

```
$("#"+opt.id).text("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

This would resolve the problem:

```
    option.textContent = "-";
```

Comment: Can you gove more context on how that will solve the problem

Comment: I don't know the reason; just encountered same issue recently and it's fixed. textContent is not a particular field of option (it's similar to innerHTML)